# Special characters from xml files are showing question marks on JSP? java web

Tags: java, xml, jsp, character-encoding, special-characters

Have a simple java web application that uses a dictionary api to fetch data and shows it on a **JSP**.

But this **character** from the XML file is **showing a question mark** when processed?
[image: xml file, notice the underlined character]

Here you can see the character showing a **?** instead of the original.

[image: output on a website from reading the xml]

How can this be solved? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this in your web.xml

```
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

If you have only one such jsp you can try adding the following page directive in the jsp

```
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```